# Can I Run Multiple Django Projects on One Website?

Tags: python, django

i'm a bit of a newcomer to Django/Python but trying to figure something out--hope you can help.

I'm trying to create a personal website with a page dedicated to some of the Python and Django projects that I've completed through several different online courses.

I'm just having a tough time figuring out the best way to link through and assemble the project directories on my server.

My first project is just the files for my blog itself.  I've created a new directory in the same home root as the blog project housing another of my django projects.  Just looking for a bit of assistance on how i link out to the second project from my blog.

I thought i could use the urls.py file for my blog to redirect link to the second project (ie projects/project2) utilizing a views definition from the views.py file for one of the apps in the blog. But then--i'm getting tripped up on how to render that link to the second project.

Any forward guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you comfortable with the [difference between a project and an application](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/applications/#projects-and-applications)?

Comment: I do believe so.  The only reason i'm asking this question is that these 'projects' were built as projects --not apps--but the more I start to think about it--maybe what I'm trying to do is just not the right way of doing things.

Answer (score 3):

In general, anything that makes sense to be served under different domain (not necessarily subdomain) would better be a separate project for sure. Exceptional case would be a project with almost same functionality but different branding within same organization. In such case, Django's built-in [sites framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/)  can be considered.

For **different projects**, you need different project roots along with different wsgi/port bindings and processes. They can still be listed within a single nginx configuration as a deployment example. Another popular way is using [Docker](https://www.docker.com) but deployment methods vary.

For **different apps** in a single project, there is only one binding and one root already. Create apps and list them in your `settings.py` and `urls.py`. If you need subdomains with single deployment, [tkaemming/django-subdomains](https://github.com/tkaemming/django-subdomains) might be helpful.

For **different policies** (rarely) in a single app under different domains, learn about [sites framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/). You need to hand code the difference in views.

and so on...